# How to make pdf file password protected?

Tags: java, pdf

I want to make pdf file password protected. I just goolge it for the same and find a good solution given below. It's working fine But it wipe out all the data which is already there in my pdf after i secure pdf using below given code.

Used jar files for this code are:

itextpdf-5.2.1.jar

bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar

bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar

bctsp-jdk16-1.46.jar

Code to secure PDF :

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Secure_file {
    private static String USER_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static String OWNER_PASSWORD = "secured";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("E:\\sample.pdf"));
            writer.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("This is Password Protected PDF document."));
            document.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

what changes i need to made in this program ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look up the [iText in Action keywords](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php) you'll find [encryption](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=194) pointing to the sample part3.chapter12.[EncryptionPdf](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=219). That sample's method `createPdf` essentially is equivalent to your code but the method `encryptPdf` is what you want:

```
/** User password. */
public static byte[] USER = "Hello".getBytes();
/** Owner password. */
public static byte[] OWNER = "World".getBytes();

...

public void encryptPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,
        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot. you made my day. It's working like a charm. Now i want to do the same for other file extension like word,jpg,excel. So is there any library to do the same?

Comment: Word and excel should be possible, probably using ms office interop or some non-ms library. I doubt it is possible for jpeg. You should make this an explicit question, not a comment.

Comment: The program worked, but the pdf is opening as secured. But instead i expect it to prompt for password.

Comment: Have you probably used an empty string as user password?

Answer (score 1):

example using iText5. If use iText7 is very similar but using another class instead of stampler.

```
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(dp.getStream());
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("someFilename", FILE_EXTENSION_PDF);
                tempFile.deleteOnExit();
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);

                String pdfPassword = "1234"
                String pdfAdminPassword = "5678"
                stamper.setEncryption(
                        pdfPassword.getBytes(),
                        pdfAdminPassword.getBytes(),
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                        PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

                reader.close();
                stamper.close();

                InputStream encryptedFileIs = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
```

or apache lib pdfbox

```
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(dp.getStream());
                AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
                StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("1234", "1234", ap);
                spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
                spp.setPermissions(ap);
                document.protect(spp);

                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("someFilename", FILE_EXTENSION_PDF);
                tempFile.deleteOnExit();
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                document.save(os);
                document.close();
                InputStream encryptedFileIs = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
```

Good luck and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

I've used this code to add password for the pdf. it will ask for the password while opening the pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have used FOP refer this [document](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/pdfencryption.html)

```
FOUserAgent userAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
useragent.getRendererOptions().put("encryption-params", new PDFEncryptionParams(
        null, "password", false, false, true, true));
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, userAgent);
```

Comment: The op wanted to password-protect an already existing PDF, not a PDF he was about to create using FOP.