# Extracting Password Protected Files inside ZIP file without losing the protection

Tags: java, encryption, unzip, zip4j

I am trying to extract a ZIP file which contains a Password Protected PDF file. Below is my Code for Extracting ZIP file.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("C:\\Users\\sathesh\\Desktop\\temp.zip"));
        if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword("abcd1234");
        }
        zipFile.extractAll("D:\\temp\\final");
```

Once the Code is executed ZIP file is getting extracted but i am losing password protecting applied on PDF file. How to extract a ZIP file without losing the Password Protection on the files. 
**NOTE** : If i comment `zipFile.setPassword("abcd1234");` then i'm getting exception

> Exception in thread "main" net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: empty or null password provided for AES Decryptor
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip.initExtractFile(Unzip.java:163)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip.initExtractAll(Unzip.java:83)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip.extractAll(Unzip.java:73)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile.extractAll(ZipFile.java:488)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile.extractAll(ZipFile.java:451)
>       at Shiva.ZipProtect.zipFileUsingPassProtect(ZipProtect.java:51)
>       at Shiva.ZipProtect.main(ZipProtect.java:25)
>   Caused by: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: empty or null password provided for AES Decryptor
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine.unzipFile(UnzipEngine.java:98)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip.initExtractFile(Unzip.java:160)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: empty or null password provided for AES Decryptor
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.crypto.AESDecrypter.init(AESDecrypter.java:99)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.crypto.AESDecrypter.(AESDecrypter.java:65)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine.initDecrypter(UnzipEngine.java:202)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine.init(UnzipEngine.java:185)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine.getInputStream(UnzipEngine.java:118)
>       at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine.unzipFile(UnzipEngine.java:78)
>       ... 7 more

I am using **Zip4j** for creating the and extracting the ZIP file.

Comment: what do you mean with *but i am losing password protecting applied on PDF file*?

Comment: I am able to open the PDF file without giving the password for the PDF file.

Comment: Isn't the end result of this operation an exploded ZIP file into a directory?

Comment: I think you may be confusing the password on the ZIP file with the password on the PDF file.

Comment: `zipFile.extractAll("D:\\temp\\final");` after this line PDF is created without password protection in `final` folder.

Comment: I believe you need to use a library for encrypting a PDF, q.v. [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681239/how-to-make-pdf-file-password-protected).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ZIP file we are creating using `Zip4j` library. Because it may contain excel, word document or another ZIP file. While creating the ZIP file we are applying the Password for the files using `ZipParameters zipParams = new ZipParameters();` and `zipParams.setPassword("1234abcd");`