# Unable to create password protected existing PDF file

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to make password protected PDF file which is already created in my directory .

Below is my sample code:

```
try {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("D:/test/SI1491232250299.pdf");
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("D:/test/SI1491232250299.pdf"));
    pdfStamper.setEncryption("abc".getBytes(), "abc".getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
    pdfStamper.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After execution got java.io.EOFException exception

Comment: Did you already add pdfStamper.createXmpMetadata(); after setEncryption method?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused about createXmpMetadata method. I guess that you need a PdfWriter (that has this method) to set the encryption.

Comment: sorry ,I didn't add  pdfStamper.createXmpMetadata(); before setEncryption method .

Comment: while debugging code I got below exception :

Comment: java.io.EOFException ...in pdfStamper.close();   can you please share sample code for same ??

Comment: I was referred to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681239/how-to-make-pdf-file-password-protected )code for the same ..but it will create  new pdf which I don't require ...

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem when you try to encrypt another PDF? Maybe the PDF you are trying to encrypt has a specific error that causes the problem. In that case, you shouldn't blame iText, but blame the PDF file for being faulty. Also: which version of iText are you using? We had a similar problem in the iText 5.2.x series (which is why we removed those versions from every server we could find).

Comment: Please use different file names to read from and write to. Itext is not designed to manipulate a pdf in place.